# copying and pasting values in to same row in mastersheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, which copies and pastes columns from a worksheet called copySheet and pastes to sheet called pasteSheet to the first empty row.

```
 lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  With copySheet.Range("BX2:BX" & lRow)
   pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
  End With

 'Determine last row of Column B in copySheet
  lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 With copySheet.Range("CC2:CC" & lRow)
 pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
 End With
```

Now i would like to copy column BB (starting from BB2) and AK (starting from AK2) from "copySheet" and paste it together to Column L in "pasteSheet". BB and AK values should have one blank between each other in same cell. Does anyone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get 2 cells, concatenate them together with a space, then set that value into another sheet?  You can do this easily enough with a `For` loop:

```
For myLoop = 2 to lRow 
    ' recalc firstEmptyRow and increment to get first empty row
    firstEmptyRow = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    myVal = copySheet.Range("BB" & myLoop).Value & " " & _
    copySheet.Range("AK" & myLoop).Value
    pasteSheet.Range("L" & firstEmptyRow).value = myVal 
Next
```

I have assumed in this case that you want the value posted to the same row in pasteSheet that you copied from in copySheet; if not, you would have to change the location in the `pasteSheet.Range` line

Comment: Thank you! i have one question thought ; i actually want it to be pasted to first empty row in that column, what should i select as pasteSheet.Range then ?

Comment: `pasteSheet.Range("L" & lRow + 1).value = myVal` will paste into the first empty sheet in `L`

Comment: You would also probably want to recalculate `lRow` once you set the value, as otherwise you'll keep pasting the value into the same cell in column `L`

Comment: I've edited the answer to demonstrate how I'd approach it.  set `lRow` to last row plus 1 at the start of each loop and you'll always paste into the first empty row in `L`

Comment: i checked it now, i have 5 copysheets so i use this 5 times by copy/pasting and changing the code to copySheet1, copySheet2... until copySheet5. however it copies and pastes more stuff then it should copy/paste. whats the reason for this?

Comment: I can't really tell without seeing your spreadsheet or code exactly what "more stuff than it should" actually means, but on second glance at the code, I was looping until `lRow` but also then incrementing `lRow` each time round.  I've edited the code again to use a different value for the first empty row, as you really shouldn't change the end point of a loop while inside it...